# Pythonesque blocks and postfix expressions

Tags: syntax, indentation, language-design

In JavaScript,

```
f = function(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
(5)
```

seems at a glance as though it should assign `f` the successor function, but actually assigns the value 6, because the lambda expression followed by parentheses is interpreted by the parser as a postfix expression, specifically a function call. Fortunately this is easy to fix:

```
f = function(x) {
    return x + 1;
};
(5)
```

behaves as expected.

If Python allowed a block in a lambda expression, there would be a similar problem:

```
f = lambda(x):
    return x + 1
(5)
```

but this time we can't solve it the same way because there are no semicolons. In practice Python avoids the problem by not allowing multiline lambda expressions, but I'm working on a language with indentation-based syntax where I do want multiline lambda and other expressions, so I'm trying to figure out how to avoid having a block parse as the start of a postfix expression. Thus far I'm thinking maybe each level of the recursive descent parser should have a parameter along the lines of 'we have already eaten a block in this statement so don't do postfix'.

Are there any existing languages that encounter this problem, and how do they solve it if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python *has* semicolons. This is perfectly valid (though ugly and not recommended) Python code: `f = lambda(x): x + 1; (5)`.

There are many other problems with multi-line lambdas in otherwise standard Python syntax though. It is completely incompatible with how Python handles indentation (whitespace in general, actually) inside expressions - it doesn't, and that's the complete opposite of what you want.  You should read the numerous python-ideas thread about multi-line lambdas. It's somewhere between very hard to impossible.

If you want arbitrarily complex compound statements inside lambdas you can't use the existing rules for multi-line expressions even if you made all statements expressions. You'd have to change the indentation handling (see the language reference for how it works right now) so that expressions can also contain blocks. This is hard to do without breaking perfectly fine Python code, and will certainly result in a language many Python programmers will consider worse in several regards: Harder to understand, more complex to implement, permits some stupid errors, etc.

Most languages don't solve this exact problem at all. Most candidates (Scala, Ruby, Lisps, and variants of these three) have explicit end-of-block tokens. I know of two languages that have the same problem, one of which (Haskell) has been mentioned by another answer. Coffeescript also uses indentation without end-of-block tokens. It parses the transliteration of your example [correctly](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3af%20=%20x%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%20+%201%0A%285%29). However, I could not find any specification of how or why it does this (and I won't dig through the parser source code). Both differ significantly from Python in syntax as well as design philosophy, so their solution is of little (if any) use for Python.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, there is an implicit semicolon whenever you start a line with the same indentation as a previous one, assuming the parser is in a layout-sensitive mode.

More specifically, after a token is encountered that signals the start of a (layout-sensitive) block, the indentation level of the first token of the first block item is remembered.  Each line that is indented more continues the current block item; each line that is indented the same starts a new block item, and the first line that is indented less implies the closure of the block.

How your last example would be treated depends on whether the `f =` is a block item in some block or not.  If it is, then there will be an implicit semicolon between the lambda expression and the `(5)`, since the latter is indented the same as the former.  If it is not, then the `(5)` will be treated as continuing whatever block item the `f =` is a part of, making it an argument to the lamda function.

The details are a bit messier than this; look at the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7).

Comment: Right, that much I have already implemented; but there is still the case I gave an example of, where the indentation is _not_ the same as the previous line.

Comment: Your last example would likely be a parse error under a Haskell-style parsing scheme.  Assuming that the `f = ...` is a block item, the `(5)` would be taken as the next block item in that block.  If  `f = ...` is not a block item, then the scheme would of course treat the `(5)` as an argument to the lambda function.